# Selected state in jQuery Accordian

Tags: css, jquery-ui

I'm just using the jQuery accordion in its basic form. I can't, for the life of me, find the selected class in this thing. I basically just want to do some css like:

```
#accordion h2 a.selected {
color: #000;
}
```

So that while your one item is selected or active, the header link stays black

I know this dead simple, and I've done it with other stuff, I'm just a little lost in the documentation for this accordion. Is it a different class? Is it something I need to add first to this?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
    autoHeight: false,
    navigation: true,
    header: 'h2'
    });
});
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chrome's Inspector saves the day!

Here are the classes I found:

```
ui-accordion-header ui-helper-reset ui-state-active ui-corner-top
```

I'd guess this should do it:

```
.ui-state-active a {
  ...
}
```

Comment: YES! Thank you. Man, that thing needs a list of every class in it. Or a section called "well....duh." I'd be there all the time. haha.

Thanks again.

Comment: I just Googled the Jquery UI example of this and inspected the accordion thing. Firebug can do the same if you have Firefox. That DOM inspector wizardry is really useful stuff!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following CSS

```
.ui-state-active a { color: #000;}
```

if that doesn't work, try making it a little more specific.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you're using not only [this jQuery accordion](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Accordion) but also one of the jQuery UI themes... [like this one](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css).

If we take a look at line `350`, we'll see this rule which is setting the CSS `color` property:

```
.ui-state-active a,
.ui-state-active a:link,
.ui-state-active a:visited {
    color: #212121/*{fcActive}*/;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

So let's do some math and [calculate that selector's specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity):

- Is it in the style attribute:?           `0`
- Number of id selectors?                  `0`
- Number of attributes and pseudo-classes? `5`
- Number of element names?                 `3`

... so your new rule has to be more specific than `0,0,5,3`. Easy way to do that: add an id selector:

```
#accordion .ui-state-active a { /* 0, 1, 1, 1 > 0, 0, 5, 3 */ }
```

Check out the [JsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TQdQL/).